# laravel 5 datatables collection not working

Tags: datatable, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-5.1, datatables-1.10

```php
$data = array(
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'john@email.com'], 
    ['name' => 'Robert Roe', 'email' => 'robert@email.com']
);
$users = new Collection($data);

return Datatables::of($users)->make();
```

I'm using the yajra/laravel-datatables plugin, it shows me that Collection functions are available on v5.x and later, but after i installed v5.11.10, and tried the above code, it gives me a `Class 'Collection' not found` error.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a namespace issue. Make sure:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

is included at the top of your controller.